# How can I support UCS-2 for chinese / japanese characters in C?

Tags: cjk, wchar-t

I'm trying to understand how wchar_t works in C by writing a simple console program, and maybe it's not as simple as I first thought.

Here's the problem:

When I tried to get a string of characters using wscanf, it works.

```
// Code 1
wchar_t wstr[10];
wprintf(L"Enter string: ");
wscanf(L"%ls", wstr);
wprintf(L"You have entered: %ls\n", wstr);
```

Output:
    Enter character: 煮
    You have entered: 煮
    Press any key to continue . . .

Which is to be expected. But if I try to get a single character (wchar), it fails:

```
// Code 2
wchar_t wstr[10];
wprintf(L"Enter character: ");
wscanf(L"%lc", wstr); wstr[1] = L'\0';
wprintf(L"You have entered: %lc\n", wstr[0]);
```

Output:
    Enter character: 煮
    You have entered: ・
    Press any key to continue . . .

My system locale is currently set to Japanese (Japan). Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: It is operating system specific and locale specific.

Comment: On what platform is this? Linux or Windows? Also, do you have the exact unicode codepoint for that character? -> code point is \U716e

Comment: I'm using windows 7 Premium, and the value of wstr[0] is 0.

Comment: Sorry, wstr[0] is 142.

Comment: Upon further probing, wstr[0] is 0x8e. wstr[1] is 0xcf. This matches 0x8ecf on Shift-JIS encoding.I don't understand why the character is stored in 2 wchar_t elements in the array instead of one.

Comment: While Unicode standard 4.0 states that wchar_t can be as small as 8bits (compiler-dependent), sizeof(wchar_t) returns 2 bytes on my computer.

Comment: Windows 7 console seems to read input as a single byte character. This explains why the 2-byte character '煮' (0x8ecf) has been split into two wchar_t elements (0x8e and 0xcf). The same applies in printf: 0x8ecf gives '?' while 0x8e and 0xcf returns the correct character '煮'.